# Uploadnsell: terms of service nowhere to be found

Tags: download, paypal, upload

Someone asked me where he could sell digital files.

I have found Uploadnsell which promises to take no commissions at all.
Customer pays to the uploader's PayPal account, and can download from Uploadnsell's website.

It seems almost too good to be true, but there is something suspicious:
The uploader has to check `I agree to the Terms of Service of UPLOADnSELL.com`, but the terms of service are nowhere to be found...

Is there a similar service with clearer terms of service?
Or did I somehow miss them?

Comment: Don't use it. I did the other day and before I even made a sale, my ebook was up on the internet torrented. It was done just after I uploaded my book. Uploadnsell is a scam, they take your property and put it up on the internet. There is zero privacy or protection going through them. You get what you pay for!! I ended up moving to the afforable Pulley app ($6/month). Worth it so your stuff doesn't end up making the rounds for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While they should certainly disclose the location of their terms they do exist.  Head over to http://uploadnsell.com/tos.php.  By the incomplete page layout I would guess that they are pretty new and still setting themselves up, but the terms are their.  Seems they may be located out of Malaysia as their dispute/claims address for their designated agent is Kengkawan IT Solutions located in Malaysia, which can be found at the very bottom of the terms.

Another service that seems to have the same options is http://pulleyapp.com.  I have no personal knowledge of their quality of service, but they do seem to have a much more complete site and have links to their [Merchant User Agreement](http://pulleyapp.com/agreement), [Terms of Service](http://pulleyapp.com/terms), and [Privacy Policy](http://pulleyapp.com/privacy).